# Inner Product spaces with functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I understand inner product space with vectors, but the conversion to functions is throwing me off. Also why do they use an integral here, I've always seen summations. I think I'm missing something with notation here. Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuitive explanation of $L^2$-norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807204/intuitive-explanation-of-l2-norm)

Answer (score 0):

First, remember that an integral is a summation under a limit, if that helps with understanding why that could possibly be an inner product.

Second, remember that $C([0,1])$ *is* a vector space.  The functions *are* vectors.  You can add two functions together, there is a constant zero function, you can multiply functions by scalars.  If you wish, think of a function as a vector with infinitely many indices: i.e., $f_x=f(x)$ for all $x$ from $0$ to $1$, rather than just integers.

Third, it is an inner product because of the axioms [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).  The integral will work out as an inner product for basically the same reason the finite-dimensional version did: they both involve a sum of products of components.

(By the way, the summation sign is a Greek sigma, for sum, and the integral sign is a "long s" because Liebniz thought of it as an infinite sum of infinitesimal summands -- it is the smooth/continuous version of summation.)

Answer (score 0):

They are *defining* the inner product in this sense. It is true that this is an inner product similar to what you know from basic linear algebra. But put that aside for a moment.

You have probably been given some properties of inner products, e.g. that $\|f\| = \sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}$. If the thing that has been given to you is in fact an inner product, then it must satisfy these properties.

So let us compute, for instance, $\|f\|$ with the definition we have been handed:

$$\|f\| = \sqrt{\langle f, f\rangle} = \left(\int_0^1 t^2 t^2\, dt\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{\frac15 \left.t^5 \right|_0^1} = \sqrt{\frac15}.$$

That's it. The rest should follow.

Answer (score 0):

An inner product $V$ on a **real** vector space $E$ is a **form** which is **symmetric positive definite**. This means that:

1. form: $V:E\times E\mapsto\mathbb{R}$,
2. symmetric: for all $x,y\in E$, we have that $V(x,y)=V(y,x)$,
3. positive: for all $x\in E$, we have that $V(x,x)\ge0$,
4. definite: if for some $x\in E$, we have that $V(x,x)=0$, then $x=0$.

If $E=\mathbb{R}^n$, it is easy to see that $V(x,y)=x^Ty$ satisfies all those properties.

We can also see that if we take $E=\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ which is the space of all $\mathbb{R}$-valued infinite sequences $(x_0,x_1,\ldots)$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i^2<\infty$, then the form $$V(x,y):=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_iy_i$$ is also an inner-product on $E$.

Now, consider $E=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ which is the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Recall also that an integral is also a sum, that is we have that

$$\int_0^1f(t)dt=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(t_i),\ t_i=i/n$$

which comes from the definition of a Riemann integral. So, the integral can be seen as averaged infinite sum.

Therefore, one can see that
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(t_i)g(t_i),\ t_i=i/n$$
which as a very similar structure as the inner-product on $\ell^2$ where $x_i=f(t_i)$ and $y_i=g(t_i)$; the only difference being the factor $1/n$.

One can easily prove that this is indeed an inner product as it verifies all the conditions stated earlier.

So, in the end, an integral is nothing else but a continuous sum that acts on spaces of functions with continuous domain. Those functions can then be seen as vectors with infinitely many (a continuum) of indices.